# Proving the derivative of $a^{x}$ is $a^{x}\ln(a)$ without using taylor series or exponential identities just the definition of derivative.

Tags: limits, derivatives

I encountered this problem in high school math textbook.

It was asking to show that if $f(x) = a^{x}$ then show that $f'(x)=a^{x}\ln(a)$ using the definition of the derivative.

I'm only aware of how to prove this relationship by using taylor series or the identity

$$e^{x}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

I was wondering can someone come up with a way simple to prove it so that a high school student without understanding of taylor series or exponential identities can understand the proof?

Comment: "without ... exponential identities..." that's a tall order. If this high school student in question understands the basics of derivatives, I imagine exponential identities are also within reach

Comment: Well, first you have to decide how to define $a^x$ and $\ln(x)$.

Comment: Your limit is irrelevant, because you want to calculate $\frac{|a^t -a^x|}{|t-x|} $ as t getting close to x.

Comment: @carmichael561 Its from a high school math textbook. I'm not sure if the textbook has defined $a^{x}$ or $ln(x)$.

Comment: @user262291 It assumed you already know that.

Comment: @user262291 then it makes no sense to ask a proof for $f'(x) = a^x \ln(a)$.

Comment: It is a common *sin* committed by many textbook authors who do not define $a^{x} $ and $\log x$ and yet expect the readers to have a sound understanding of the limit in question here. Moreover defining such things is hard and it is better to present these things without proof to a high school student. After all no one raises an eyebrow when a 12 year old gets to know that $\pi$ is irrational (without proof).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we denote $$f(x)=a^x$$ taking the logarithm on both sides we obtain:
$$\ln(f(x))=x\ln(a)$$ and by the cain rule we get
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln(a)$$
and multiplying by $$f(x)$$ we get the desired result.

---

or $$\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=a^x\left(\frac{a^h-1}{h}\right)$$
and use that the limit in brackets is equal to $\ln(a)$ for $a>0$

Comment: i have it provided

Comment: Now the question that can you prove $\lim_{h\to 0}{e^h - 1\over h } = 1$ without taylor series ?

Comment: to prove this limit set $$t=a^h-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=a^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{h}-1}{h}$$

Note that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$$

So

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\ln a\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h\ln a}-1}{h\ln a}\right)=\ln a$$